# How to bind a float or double with JGoodies

Tags: java, swing, binding, double, jgoodies

I have done binding with ints and longs with no probelems. I just use BasicComponentFactory.createIntegerField or LongField. There is no such thing for floats or doubles. Is there a way to do bind these primitives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ValueModel valueModelxField = adapter.getBufferedModel("x");
xJTextField = BasicComponentFactory.createFormattedTextField(valueModelxField, new DecimalFormat("0.#####"));
```

This is how I got it to work.